# How to Split string value in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a following string

```
90-PMR-450
90-PMRA-340
```

I want to get part 3 of string. example `450` or `340`.

plese help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you will find this user defined function to split the string helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @T table
(
  Value varchar(15)
)

insert into @T values
('90-PMR-450'),
('90-PMRA-340')  

select stuff(Value, 1, 1+len(Value)-charindex('-', reverse(Value)), '')
from @t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(v VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x SELECT '90-PMR-450'
UNION ALL SELECT '90-PMRA-340';

SELECT Part3 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(v, '-', '.'), 1) FROM @x;
```